# Why is the Seed method not running on database creation

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Please see the code below:

```
public class MyReadContext
    {
        public MyReadContext()
            : base()
            //: base("DefaultConnection")
        {
            Database.SetInitializer<MyReadContext>(new DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<MyReadContext>());
        }

        public DbSet<Product> products { get; set; }

        public class MyReadInitializer : DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<MyReadContext>
        {
            protected override void Seed(MyReadContext context)
            {
                context.products.Add(
                  new Product { description = "Product1" }
                );
                base.Seed(context);
            }
        }
    }
```

The Seed method is not called when the database is initially created by EF Code First i.e. I add a breakpoint on the Seed signature and it is never reached.  Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to call `await context.SaveChangesAsync()` or synchronously  `context.SaveChanges()`

change this line

```
Database.SetInitializer<MyReadContext>(new DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<MyReadContext>());
```

to

```
Database.SetInitializer<MyReadContext>(new MyReadInitializer());
```

then add save context

```
public class MyReadInitializer : DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<MyReadContext>
        {
            protected override void Seed(MyReadContext context)
            {
                context.products.Add(
                  new Product { description = "Product1" }
                );
                context.SaveChanges()
                base.Seed(context);

            }
    }
```

Comment: Cointext.SaveChanges is called in the Repository.  The constructor is reached, however the Seed method is not.

Comment: Thanks, but in my question I state that the Seed method is not even reached.

Comment: @w0051977 have you tried what I updated? I am not sure that you are able to debug when database update

Comment: the Seed method is not even reached, so how will this resolve it?

Comment: @w0051977 how do you know that its not reached?

Comment: because there is a breakpoint inside the function.  I will try your code, but I am not optimistic.

Comment: @w0051977 be positive my friend :D

Comment: As expected, this has not worked.  The Seed method is not even reached.  Do you have any other ideas?

Comment: @w0051977 how are you running update of database from code? or commandline?

Comment: @w0051977 i missed one thing check answer

Comment: Thanks.  That does work.  However, it will attempt to add the same product every time it starts.  Won't it?

Comment: @w0051977 everytime when model is changed. In your case its not a problem because you drop database. But in real world you dont want to drop database :)

Comment: How do you stop a developer from accidentally dropping a live database? Is there a way in EF?

Comment: @w0051977 you should use migrations https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj554735(v=vs.113).aspx

Comment: Can you INSERT records using migrations?

Comment: @w0051977 Yes migration has method Sql("You write custom sql you need"). But you dont have access to context so you can write plain string sql

Comment: Thanks.  One more thing.  Why would you use .sql in a migration instead of a seed method in an initializer?

Comment: @w0051977 thats a good question. Maybe because I use to work in that way, Maybe I dont need it very often, and lastly if you are changing your entities code it could be that some properties are gone. For instance you have one-to-many then you are making many-to-many your code will simply not compile

Comment: @w0051977 and some times you simply need to update db in specific order. Add table, run sql, drop column. or something similar

Comment: I assume you use a Migration in the former and a Seed in the latter?

Comment: @w0051977 yes. Basically i am using seed only in Tests. When i need to fill some data. So after all my migrations are applied then seed will fill data

Comment: Thanks.  That is it.